# Error in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in IOS - objective-c app development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova

In my 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' function i am giving following line at the end :-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

But it is giving the following warning:-

```
'NSObject' may not respond to 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' function
```

And when i build it, the application terminates with 'Uncaught Exception error'

Can anybody suggest why this is happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[self application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Base objct like NSObject dont implement method of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions`

Comment: DUDE i tried that ..its running into an infinite loop. because of that.. ie. calling finishLaunchingWithOptions function repeatedly.

Comment: so dont invoke it. Well what i the real problem? hat are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes i found out that its not required to invoked.

Comment: What was the problem then? And what is the solution?

Comment: problem was i was invoking it again and again. So i stopped that.

Answer (score 0):

you should return YES at the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
return YES;
```